# Ctrl+D doesn't stop application from executing in command window

Tags: c

I've written a program to encrypt a given message by XOR. It works, but It doesn't end. Here is the code.(I have created 3 files):

encrypt.h :

```
void encrypt(char *message);
```

message_hider.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "encrypt.h"

int main() {
  char msg[80];

  while (fgets(msg, 80, stdin)){
    encrypt(msg);
    printf("%s", msg);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

encrypt.c :

```
#include "encrypt.h"

void encrypt(char *message) {
  while (*message) {
    *message++ ^= 0x1f;
  }
}
```

As I mentioned above, It works. but I can't stop it. When I pressed Ctrl+D to stop it (in cmd) It encrypts it also.(I need this code stop after it encrypt a message). Please explain me about this case.

Comment: As you wrote this. Can you explain under what situation you expected this code to stop?

Comment: cmd does not understand Ctrl+D, use end-of-file condition (i.e. write a file and give it to your program on stdin: `prog < file`). And you don't encrypt, you obfuscate (a little). BTW, don't expect printf be able to actually display the obfuscated text.

Comment: You use a worse subject, please modify it to meaningful.

Comment: @fork0 (1) Windows `cmd` recognizes Ctrl+Z as EOF; (2) this is indeed an encryption using a simple substitution cipher, just like how [ROT13 is a substitution cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rot13).

Comment: the line edited by Brad is Ok, but it encrypt the return character also.

Comment: please also tag your question with information about the platform that you are using

Comment: @0xEDD1E what line did Brad edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isprint()` can help:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void encrypt(char *message)
{
    while (*message) {
        *message = *message ^ 31;
        message++;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char msg[80];

    while (fgets(msg, 80, stdin) != NULL) {
        if (!isprint((unsigned char)*msg)) break;
        encrypt(msg);
        printf("%s", msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> When I pressed Ctrl+D to stop it (in cmd)

If that's the `cmd` from Windows you probably want `Ctrl+Z`.

Answer (score 5):

**Ctrl-D** is used for the console EOF on Unix systems.

**Ctrl-Z** is used for the console EOF on Windows systems.

Comment: Press Ctrl-Z+Enter in cmd.exe on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Add an exit condition:

```
if( c < 0x20 ) break;
```

You may need to add other checks also to support backspace without encoding it...

http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 0):

Just run

```
  $> kill -l
```

To see the list of signals in Linux. You will not find SIGKILL (Ctrl + D) signal there :(

Ctrl + D is SIGKILL (0) signal in Linux which is not documented anywhere.
Ctrl + Z is for Windows which tell EOF and we need to press "Enter" to close.

Comment: This is incorrect. Ctrl-D doesn't cause a signal to be sent on unix. SIGKILL is typically signal 9, not 0. The value 0 doesn't have a standard name assigned to it.