# How to end a c program with Ctrl+D in windows?

Tags: c, eof

SO in linux i could probably end a while-loop with this kind of code if I compile with gcc:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{   
    int s;
    while(scanf("d%",&s)!=EOF);
    {   
        scanf("%d",&s);
          }
    return 0;
}
```

However this does not work with a windows computer and the compiler Im using is Microsoft Visual Studio 12. Any suggestions?

Comment: Anything wrong with Alt+F4? (Or is that what you were looking for)

Comment: `scanf` does not return `EOF`, you are thinking of `getchar`...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ctrl+D not stopping application from executing in command window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001894/ctrld-not-stopping-application-from-executing-in-command-window)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int s;
    while((s = getchar()) != EOF) {
        printf("%d\n", s);
    }
    printf("%d - at EOF\n", s);
}
```

you can try this

Comment: Just a question on this, if I want to print something in the whileloop before the user gets to input data, how could I do then? because now it prompts the user the first thing it does in the program?

Answer (score 1):

Try it with strg + c or strg + z. I think that was which overgives the EOF

Comment: does does not work either for me, atleast not for this code : (

Comment: <kbd>^Z</kbd> *followed by Return* in a DOS window is equivalent to <kbd>^D</kbd> in a Unixy tty.

Comment: Strangely, if I create a loop with while(1>0) , Ctrl+c ends the program, do you Think my teacher will be pleased with that? :p

Comment: @zwol: MS-DOS follows the CP/M convention of treating control-Z as an EOF indicator when a file or stream is open in text mode.  The control-D behavior is a result of a "cooked mode" keyboard driver, and causes a request for input to return however many bytes have been typed since the last newline or control-D, even if that number is zero, but the control-D never becomes part of the stream.

Answer (score 0):

it's ctrl + c in windows, for some silly reason